# can't overwrite to a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I'm trying to overwrite output of a unix command to a file but it keep appending the output to the file.

```
wget --progress=dot http://test.com/example.zip 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \ 
 sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf(" %4s", $2)}' > log.txt
```

References can be found here: [Tutorial](http://fitnr.com/showing-file-download-progress-using-wget.html)

This is the output I'm getting - log.txt

```
   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   0%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   1%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   2%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%   3%
```

It should be just one percentage

```
10%
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reference you quote says `awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'` and you've omitted the `\b` that cause the output to _overwrite_ itself.

Comment: with all the `\b` 's, output shows some unrecognized symbols so I had to remove them. btw output was the same with the original code.

Comment: The ``\b`` character is a backspace which works well in the terminal but not so well redirected to a file. I think you need a different approach altogether.

Comment: @acfrancis what would you suggest?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @acfrancis I'm trying to write current file progress ( like 5% ) to a file so I can just read the file and check file progress regularly for fronted purposes.

Comment: Try replacing ``awk '{printf(" %4s", $2)}' > log.txt`` with ``awk '{system(sprintf("echo %4s > log.txt", $2))}'``

Comment: Great idea! thanks.. It works, Can you please write it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Using three tools (`grep`, `sed` and `awk`) to achieve what any one of them could do is a sign that whoever wrote the original script didn't really understand any of those tools.

Using just `awk` (and only posix awk features, afaik):

```
wget --progress=dot http://test.com/example.zip 2>&1 |
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,3}%/){printf "%4s",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) >"log.txt";
                             close("log.txt")}'
```

(I just checked this with gawk, mawk, and the original-awk (used on Mac OS X), and the last one doesn't seem to understand the brace-repetition operator, so you need to write `match($0,/[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]%/)`. With gawk, there are some possible simplifications.)

And here's a simple solution using just `grep`, although it will behave almost exactly as your original (i.e. it won't rewind the file on each line. We'll get to that.)

```
wget --progress=dot http://test.com/example.zip 2>&1 |
  grep --line-buffered -oE '[0-9]{1,3}%'
```

There are various ways to get that to overwrite a file on every line; here's a simple one:

```
for PCT in $(wget --progress=dot http://test.com/example.zip 2>&1 |
             grep --line-buffered -oE '[0-9]{1,3}%'); do
  printf '%4s\n' $PCT > log.txt
done
```